# How to create a button with "@" as label in Android?

Tags: android, layout, button, input

I'm developing a custom IME (Input Method Engine), also known as SoftKeyboard in Android, and I must create a button with "@" as label. This is somewhat tricky because the "@" character is a special one, used by the SDK to parse the .xml layout files. I've also tried to put an [& # 0 0 6 4 ;] (HTML @'s encoding), but it also gives me an error.
**What I need: a button with "@" as label**. Any hints?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried escaping the character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the @ in quotes "@" - odd but seems to work.  Or if you wanted literal "@" you would do `\"@\"`

Comment: I've put "\@" (double quotes, inverted bar, at sign, double quotes), and worked for me. It appears as \@ (inverted bar, at sign) in the xml, but when running in the device it appeared as it should appear.
Thanks for the hint (inverted bar)!